# How to load XSD files in spring when the app is working offline

Tags: java, spring, xsd, spring-bean

I have gone through multiple stackoverflow threads but couldn't find a solution so posting this question. This is regarding how the xsd's are being mapped in spring container.

Below is the configuration in the context.xml

```
<beans 
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
```

This works perfectly when the application is connected to internet, but the problem is when it works offline. It throws below error on start-up.

> Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 7; columnNumber:
> 68; cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.

If I explicitly point to the classpath like this,it works.

```
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
   classpath:/org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans.xsd"
```

As per my understanding, Every spring jar shipped with the xsd and it is being mapped in META-INF/spring.schemas. The refered xds in the xml file should be able to load the local xsd available in the jar.

My concern is

1. Why it is unable to load the local xsd when there is no internet?
2. Of-course I can refactor all the xsi:schemaLocation to load from classpath but I have more than 25 xml files so instead of changing in all of them is there a better way to deal with it?

Spring version - spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar
spring.schemas -

```
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-4.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-4.1.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-4.2.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-4.3.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.1.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.2.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.3.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util.xsd
```

Comment: This should just work. If it doesn't you aren't telling us something, like are you shoehorning everything into a fatjar using the maven-shade plugin?

Comment: Nothing like that, surprisingly the same configuration works for other module. That is why I'm unable to figure out what could be the issue.

Comment: Do you have conflicting dependencies? Could you share a `pom.xml` or Gradle `build.gradle`?